# Entity Framework Plus. A new entity is not returned with cache

Tags: entity-framework-plus

I use Entity Framework Plus with FromCache option with EF6.
My problem is that after adding a new item the cache that returned doesn't contain the item.
Is it possible to "update" the cache automatically after a new item added?

Save a new policy:

```
 db.policies.Add(policy);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

Get the all policies:

```
database.policies.FromCache().ToList();
```

EF Plus has CacheItemPolicy but I have to supply SqlCommand for the class that I do not have as you can see in the example of saving an item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the option `IsAutoExpireCacheEnabled` for EF6

```
QueryCacheManager.IsAutoExpireCacheEnabled = true;
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3WHMGk

As soon as something is added/modified/deleted, all caches related to this DbSet will be clreared.